# Differentiate between success data and error message to use in Struts 2?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, struts2

I am doing an AJAX call and using Struts 2 JSON plugin.

When the code reaches `success()` of AJAX call, I don't know how to differentiate whether I should load the *success* data or *load message* or *errors*, which I want to display it to the user if something unusual happened during the AJAX call.

As code always reaches `success()` until the AJAX request itself fails.

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT**: I came up with one idea which was to send a String too with response to Ajax and check string value (i.e) if string is set to success load the other JSON parameter returned, if error I load `error.jsp`

Answer (score 0):

If you use only JSON response then you should set the *status* code of your action result.

If you return a `json` type result then you can use

```xml
<result name="error" type="json">
    <param name="statusCode">400</param>
</result>
```

It will reach `error()` Ajax function.

If you use different response you could set the status code to the response object

```
response.setStatus(400);
```

and on `error()` you can use `jqXHR` parameter to check for `jqXHR.status`.

Comment: I had tried setting status code to 200 for success, but 200 already is set to status if AJAX request was success. Can u explain with some code?

Comment: This question also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856712/actionerror-not-getting-displayed is with same refrence.