# ActionError not getting displayed

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, struts2

I want to load my `Error.jsp` in my `ErrorDiv` if `Action` class returns error. I am doing an AJAX call.

**JS:**

```
success: function(result){    
    if(result === 'success')
        alert('Database Updated Successfully!');
    else{
         $('#ErrorDiv').load('/gma/pages/Error.jsp');
    }
}
```

**`Error.jsp`:**

```jsp
<body>

<%
    request.setAttribute("decorator", "none");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.1
    response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
    response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0); //prevents caching at the proxy server
%>
<s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
       <s:actionerror />
</s:if>

</body>
```

However, action errors are not getting displayed. In firebug I checked, response to `GET` `Error.jsp` in that the `<body> </body>` part comes empty.

Why are `actionError` not getting displayed?

**EDIT:**

**Action Class**:

```
try{
slsConfigureTspThresholdRemote.setThresholdParameters(circleId, tspId, thresholdTypeFlag, thresholdParametersList);

}
catch (Exception e){    
    addActionError(e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
    
    result = "error";
    return ERROR;
}
```

**struts.xml:**

```
<action name="updateThresholdParameters"
class="cdot.oss.cmsat.gma.struts.ConfigureTspThresholdAction" method="updateThresholdParameters">

<result name="success" type="json">
    <param name="root">result</param>
</result> 

<result name="error">pages/Error.jsp</result>
```

Presently, I am doing `$('#ErrorDiv').html(result);` so that my JSP get loaded in `div` instead of

```
$('#ErrorDiv').load('/gma/pages/Error.jsp');!
```

Comment: Can you add your action part and struts.xml action?

Comment: @VinothKrishnan: Have added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation errors are available only to the same request. Also direct access to the JSPs might be handled by the web container where the Struts tags will not work.

You should use an action to render a JSP and the action should run a [`store` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/message-store-interceptor.html) if you want to keep the validation errors from the previous request.

If you want to use the same response to return a different result you can set the different *status* code with each result.

On the client you could check the status code returned by the Ajax response and do corresponding things.

```
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    if(jqXHR.status == 200) {                      
      alert('Database Updated Successfully!'); 
    }
}
error: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    if(jqXHR.status == 400) {
      $('#ErrorDiv').html(data);        
    }     
}
```

To show errors in the JSP add the following to the scriptlet code

```
response.setStatus(400);
```

Comment: It's not a validation error. I updated my question and have posted the ACtion class. Plz see.

Comment: If instead of response.setStatus(201); I use <result name="error" type="httpheader">
        <param name="statusCode">201</param>, it will be the same?? I am using struts2-JSON plugin

Comment: No, it will not be the same.

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: The type is difference.

Comment: Can you give link which can help explain this? Or elaborate?

Comment: I didn't tell you to use `httpheader` result type. If you have another question you can write in the separate thread.