# Struts2 jquery tabbed panel on timeout not firing events

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, http-headers, struts2-jquery

Have a `<sj:tabbedppanel>` on a page.
After session timeout trying to click on another tab of tabbed panel should redirect the user to login poage. 
`<sj:tabbed>` panel not firing the `onErrorTopics`. Please see below and guide me on how to fix this issue. I am seeing in fire bug that the 403 error is thrown but I am unable to catch it in jsp. Need help with the same.

struts.xml

```xml
    <action name="secondPanel" class="com.xxx.secondPanelAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="sampleDefaultStack" />

        <result>/jsp/secondPanel.jsp</result> 
        <result name="login" type="httpheader">
            <param name="error">403</param>
            <param name="errorMessage">User session expired      </param>
        </result>
    </action>
```

jsp

```xml
<sj:tabbedpanel id="remotetabs" selectedTab="0" show="true"   hide="'fade'" collapsible="true" sortable="true" onErrorTopics="loadError">
    <sj:tab id="tab2" href="%{createUrl}" key="label.create" onErrorTopics="loadError"/>
    <sj:tab id="tab1" href="%{updateUrl}" key="label.update" onErrorTopics="loadError"/>
</sj:tabbedpanel>

<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function() {  
      $.subscribe('loadError', function(event, data) { alert('in error');
      var status = event.originalEvent.status;

      if(status == 403 ) {
          window.location.href = "/Sample/login.action";
      }
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Do you enter your javascript function ? Which is the value of your var status ?

Comment: no, I am not entering the javascript function.

Comment: Do you have `<sj:head/>` in your `<head>` ?

Comment: yes, I do. I was able to display the tab panels just fine. Now trying to implement the session timeout and having issue in handling it. I can see the interceptor worked fine and the 403 result sent back from server but the client side it's not entering the java script function.

Comment: Could you try using "status" instead of "error" in the params ?

Comment: Tried that and used onSuccessTopics too but didn't trigger the event i.e didn't call the javascript function. what else can I try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made some test and here what I find.

Lets try a simple `sj:div` which is some how simpler. If you use the `httpheader` result with `status:403` then you can use some thing like:

```
<sj:div href="/security/login.ib" onErrorTopics="loadError" targets="test">Test</sj:div>

  $.subscribe('loadError', function(event, data) {
      alert('some error happend');
      if(event.originalEvent.request.status){
          var status = event.originalEvent.request.status;
          alert(status);
      }
  });
```

Please not that you should use `event.originalEvent.request.status`

Back to `sj:tab` ....

The sj:tab is not working with `onAlwaysTopics` or `onErrorTopics`, seems to be a bug. However you can use `onCompleteTopics` or may be `onChangeTopics`.

```
<sj:tabbedpanel id="remotetabs" show="true"   hide="'fade'" collapsible="true" sortable="true" onCompleteTopics="loadError" >
```

But you can not use `httpheader` result. With `status:403`, the `loadError` will not called at all.

So you can use `onCompleteTopics` in your jsp and return a json which will  let you know what should be done.

Or you can use

```
$(document).ajaxError( function(e, xhr, settings, exception) {

   if (xhr.status == 403) {
      //Do what you want

   }

}
```

Please not that the above `ajaxError` will be called for every `ajaxError`, not only when you change the tabs. May be you using `settings.url` can help.

Comment: See also [Differentiate between success data and error message to use in Struts 2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20857989/573032).